# Should we burn the Tactics tag?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tag-blacklist

The [tactics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tactics) tag has 140 questions and is defined as:

*Summary*

> For questions about short term actions, often in a military context. Consider also [military].

*Wiki*

> *Empty*

A quick review of questions tagged with [tactics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tactics) suggests the most common question type is "how can X defeat Y?"

**Question:** Should we burn the [tactics] tag?

Comment: As of the writing of this comment, this post has been viewed 70 times with only four participants. It's truly disappointing that so few Meta visitors actually participate anymore. It makes it hard to get anything done by community consensus. I really am trying to involve others rather than taking unilateral action.

Comment: We wub u JBH, keep up the good work.

Comment: Unless it conflicts with a semantic tag e.g. 'strategy' or negatively impacts the visibility of the questions on the network, no reason for immolation. In fact I suspect Google algorithm and the likes wouldn't mind a couple of extra letters if it helps to identify the nature of the text better... That's 4¢ thanks inflation!

Answer (score 2):

**Counter suggestion**

So, even though I appear to be on the loosing side (boo!) - based on some of the comments, even though I don't entirely agree with them - there may be a better way to address this than just canning the tag:

**Changing 'Tactics' to 'Doctrine'**

This shifts the focus from 'What do my Characters do in this scenario' - which isn't world building to 'How can X be realistically used in my world' - which, IMO, is World building.

Or combining the two (as the layperson is more likely to search for Tactics as a Tag than Doctrine)

Then, we could update the Wiki to articulate the difference.

**EDIT Proposed new tag 'Doctrine'**

Based on JBH's comments - We are in agreement that there is potential value in a tag for questions that deal with the types of World Building scenario where the practical application of weapons, assets etc. is an issue for the Querent - but that Tactics, being focused on what the individual is doing in the moment invariably runs afoul of being a story based question.

However - for people who want to have a military force behave in a believable manner (or at least... an internally consistent manner) or to two seemingly contradictory aspects feature heavily in their story e.g. have Guns, but also have Sword masters.

I am proposing a new tag 'Doctrine' which is for the high-level aspect of how an organization might deploy it's troops, resources, weapons etc. which fits within the remit of building a believable world, whilst seeking to provide World Builders a framework on how they can address issues in their world.

**Suggested Wiki entry below**

For Questions about how an Organization (Could be a Military, could be Militia etc. - from the top level down to the troops on the ground) would deploy various weapons systems and tactics in a believable way that supports the World Builders' goals.
For example - if you want to have both ranged weapons as an option but also want a significant focus on Melee combat. This is not 'What would my Character do in this scenario' - which is a Story Based question but it is 'How can I make the key story elements that are important to me in my world believable' - Classic Examples would be the personal shields from Dune (which 'force' Melee combat) or Warhammer 40K where the number of enemies is always far greater than the amount of Ammunition that can be carried, so fighting always ends in Melee.

Comment: There’s not a 1 to 1 mapping so we should not create a tag synonym. Doctrine is a rather broad word covering far more than just military tactics so I’d be cautious about creating it as a tag.

Comment: Having gone through this before, simply changing the name of the tag won't work because users will look at how the tag is used historically and use that to justify how they want to use it today. So, we're likely going to burn the [tag:tactics] tag... however, I'm open to a "military-doctrine" tag so long as it has a good summary and wiki. "How can X be realistically used in my world?" is, IMO, a poor example because it's little different than "what can X do in this scenario?" Further, I wouldn't want any tag to specifically embrace "realism."  (\*Continued\*)

Comment: On the other hand, a question of the form, "I'm developing the rules of engagement for my military (*enter detailed description of military here*) and I'm working to develop the doctrine relating to a specific type of engagement (*enter detailed description here*). What type of doctrine would support the goals of my military and the government (*enter detailed description here*) it serves?" would fit neatly into our worldbuilding rules. Care to edit your answer and suggest the summary and wiki that would go with such a tag?

Comment: @JBH - Will look at doing that later on :)

Comment: @JBH - Take a peak - happy to edit based on Feedback.

Comment: Change the tag name to be clear its for military doctrine only. Your example does not do a good job being related to doctrine. It’s not the technology that exists in the world it's the technology issued by a particular organization. NATO defines military doctrine as “ Fundamental principles by which the military forces guide their actions in support of objectives. It is authoritative but requires judgement in application.” the tag would need to explicitly show how tactics questions are not suitable.

Comment: @sphennings - I did think about limiting it to just Military Doctrine - but then there could be doctrinal questions that aren't explicitly military - for example Red Cross/Red Crescent type orgs in a world might have a Doctrinal need - but happy to restrict if you think it's more appropriate. I'll think on your last part and come up with a v2 - bearing in mind - first time writing a Tag Wiki article :)

Comment: In general it's best to first demonstrate that there is a reason to create a new tag that can't be serves by existing tags. Remember that part of the issue with this tag is that the questions are likely to be unsuitable for this site.

Comment: Will do a V2 tonight.

Comment: Before v1 there first there needs to be questions that need  the tag.

Comment: I agree with @sphennings that we need to keep it strictly military. There's an enormous (spelled "enormous" but pronounced "catastrophic") difference between military doctrine and religious doctrine. The tag would be nearly useless if it tries to be everything to every discipline that might use the word. However, I disagree that we need questions before the tag. That's the normal path... but we're trying to fix a problem. And who knows? In the process of disconnecting all of the questions currently tagged "tactics" we might find one or two appropriately tagged "military-doctrine."

Comment: OK... I *really love* the phrase you use, `an internally consistent manner`. That's really what we're looking for... to help worldbuilders establish rules for their world. And that's what really differentiates what we're trying to do from the [tag:tactics] tag, which is inherently an effort to tell the story and has little to nothing to do with worldbuilding rules. In other words, not a bad first pass, but for the second focus a lot on that phrase, "an internally consistent manner."

Comment: I haven't forgotten about this - just been a bit busy recently

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**

Worldbuilding is fundamentally defined as the creation and consistent use of rules governing or describing a "world," which can be anything from a hamlet to an entire universe. But the fundamental condition is *consistent use.* A question that doesn't result in a "rule" that is consistently true in all story circumstances wasn't a worldbuilding question.

A quick review of the questions tagged [tactics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tactics) reveals that most if not all are circumstantial.

**What are tactics anyway?**

According to the [US Army](https://armypubs.army.mil/epubs/DR_pubs/DR_a/ARN38160-FM_3-90-000-WEB-1.pdf), Tactics are *"the employment, ordered arrangement, and directed actions of forces in relation to each other.  Leaders select tactics that accomplish their assigned mission"* and *"Tactics require judgement in application."* In other words, tactics are the actions and choices of individual or group characters acting within a world or setting.

**An acceptable "tactic" question**

> I'm developing the military for my country and I'm working on the Rules of Engagement. Given the specific description of my military's structure, below, and the following two examples of conflicts I plan on using in my story, what would be a Rule of Engagement governing the use of the technology I describe?

Such a question eliminates *circumstances* and avoids dependency on [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609) by developing a protocol — an in-world "rule" that would be "true" in all circumstances just as military Rules of Engagement are in Real Life. Indeed, we can use examples of existing Rules of Engagement to justify and rationalize answers.

**Unacceptable "tactic" questions**

However, most of the tagged questions are of the form:

> How would X defeat Y?

Which, I believe, is entirely story-based. Does the author want X to defeat Y or not? Will the author allow any particular resource, circumstance, or opportunity, or not? In the end, the selected answer won't be objectively true in all circumstances, but will rather be the one the OP likes the most.

In a nutshell, the OP is asking for help overcoming writer's block rather than help developing the structure needed to tell stories.

**Conclusion**

I believe we should burn the [tactics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tactics) tag as the concept of tactics in a worldbuilding context is too narrow to rationalize the tag and it's too easily abused for story-based questions.

Comment: I agree that the tag should be burnt. I agree that your unacceptable tactics question is unacceptable (tag or no tag). However, I also think that your acceptable tactics query ought to *probably* be unacceptable as well. Well. It's not really about tactics per se --- it's rules of engagement, which falls under "rules of the world". Tactics to me seems much more a storybuilding question than a worldbuilding question. Ultimately, the battle plan chosen is the decision and action of one or more characters in the story, not some fundamental or even higher level rule of the world.

Comment: Rules of engagement aren't tactics as much as they are doctrine.

Comment: @sphennings From a practical perspective, that's making my point. However, for the sake of completeness and for the sake of people who may ask the question without knowing the difference, I included the example.

Comment: I'm in agreement with your post. Many people eople mistake strategy or tactics for doctrine. Making the distinction explicit and using separate terms may help clarify why ROE may be more acceptable than a question about strategy or tactics.

Answer (score 1):

*N.B. : This is a draft I found back while cleaning up my computer. As I don't like wasting expended time, I give it here. It is rough around the edges and lacking finesse I believe, but it should give some insight as an expert in tactics. More than usual, feel free to change it as needed as long as the core points remain the same; Indeed, it's highly-unlikely I will be active again, so... do it like I won't maintain this answer.*

### Tags are not enforcers of what kind of posts are written

Tags' main purpose is not to tell which kind of question is accepted or not, their main purpose is to sort them  :

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories. [From help-center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)

This may look like a wordplay, but it isn't. The difference here is that it is a tool to find questions, not to evaluate them by the inexistence of their tag. An actual worldbuilding question on a rather uncommon topic (e.g. : A question about a world of letters) may have no real viable tags, yet it can be accepted here. Inversely, the [anatomically-correct](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anatomically-correct) tag for the most part contains [questions which have an hard time being accepted anymore](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9816), but the tag still exists as an archive of questions with many interesting answers. Thinking tags are actual conditions to questions' acceptance will only restrain what makes worldbuilding and this site useful. It is part of what makes the site "physics.SE-lite", as some would say.

Even if it wasn't about that, I thought people learned the lesson with the [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science), [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based), [internal-consistency](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internal-consistency) tags being constantly used together (while they shouldn't). For the most part tags are not read, even their headlines. Tags are for the most common part not used consistently. People get reference on whether they can write a question or not through many factors, including existing questions, tour and help-center or pure "I ask without checking the rules" behavior. One single tag existence is at the extreme most a tertiary criteria, especially when similar ones exist, like [warfare](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warfare) or [weapons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons)

Supposing that "How can I defeat X" questions are 'bad', removing this tag will not change the number of them. Since "how can I defeat X" are more generally warfare questions, you'll have to remove all notions of wars or battles both in tags and in questions to eventually stop having "how can I defeat X" questions.

### The science of tactics are not about individual choices, but favorable and unfavorable states

That being said, let's focus on the deep sight of the proposal : Are tactics on-topic or not? A common theme (and JBH's own answer to this question) about telling why tactics and strategy are off-topic is that they are all about individual choices and circumstances. That's completely false and one of the most common misunderstanding about tactics and strategy in general.

Let's look at this simple situation, the ABC of aerial warfare and the one used in actual dogfight training, even nowadays :

[image: Drawing of two aerial dogfight situations. Situation 1 : Plane A is behind plaen B. Situation 2 : Plane A and plane B are facing each other]
<sup>Drawing of two aerial dogfight situations. Situation/state 1 : Plane A is behind plane B. Situation/state 2 : Plane A and plane B are facing each others. For simplicity's sake, both planes are at the same height.</sup>

You have 2 identical planes (let's say the iconical F-16), A and B. If you're in situation 1 (also known as offensive/defensive situation, depending on whether you're A or B), plane A has a clear advantage on plane B : Plane A has a large shooting window on plane B (missiles can lock-on, and with some aiming bullets can hit), while plane B has none and the enemy is in its blind spot. In comparison, situation 2 is "neutral" : None have a clear advantage, planes will pass by each other with a small firing window, and they'll need to maneuver around to gain an advantage over their opponent beyond their raw skills, leading to other situations.

So to the question "How can plane A defeat plane B?" or "How can I defeat plane B?", the only and best answer in tactics is to tell that "you need to reach situation 1", or more precisely "use your plane's speed and maneuverability to reach situation 1, the ideal state if you want to take down the plane". Point.

In contrast, whether the pilot actually wants to take down the plane, is the story. Whether they manage to reach situation 1 by managing each individual maneuver and choosing every time the good counter-maneuver to the opponent, is -in part- story. Whether they actually hit the target this time and this time only, is the story. But that is not answering the question "how can plane A defeat plane B?". None of them are answering "how" to make it happen, at most they tell "what" happens in practice for this very specific situation.

And I can tell that no tactician will find your world believable if in most confrontations plane B in state 1 wins the fight. I will not find any work consistent with the art of war as we know it if a highly-skilled pilot like the [Red Baron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manfred_von_Richthofen) ends up being plane B in situation 1 in almost every of their dogfights. Like it will be absurd to have a general manage to win easily by sending artillery and snipers at point-blank range... Or by forcing a charge against tanks on an open-field with only spoons as weapons. And while I used situation 1 as the most obvious "winning" case, this is also applicable to more "nebulous" cases like situation 2, where the balance of power is harder to decipher. The fact it is a 50% chance to win instead of 90-100% is irrelevant : pilots of equal level (and supposedly competent), regardless of their individual origins, will have a 50% of winning situation 2 on average, which is less for plane A in situation 1. That's what tactics will predict.

It is not without reason that [strategy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/strategy) and [tactics](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tactics) are thought as a [science](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/science) : It is not about choosing something and hoping it would go well, "happy-go-lucky" style. This is the exact contrary to what being knowledgeable in tactics is. It is all about predicting what are the most likely outcomes of a choice you "can" make, leading to the most favorable result at any point in time. As a discipline tactics is the accumulated knowledge of different battle states, their possible actions and their likely outcomes<sup>1</sup>. Tactics is *not* the choice of a specific tactic, nor the success/failure after having chosen and tried one.

> Asking about plot elements such as the actions of characters, rather than about the world in which your story takes place, is off-topic on Worldbuilding. Capabilities of characters within a world and creation of groups of characters (like nations) are on-topic, but questions must focus on what is possible or likely to develop, not what someone would or should do. [Why is my question "Too Story Based" and how do I get it opened?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/why-is-my-question-too-story-based-and-how-do-i-get-it-opened)

I put strong emphasis that "questions must focus on what is possible (ie. what it can be, or what it can do) or likely to develop, not what someone would or should do.". Indeed, asking what someone would do is not the same as asking what they "can" do. Both are also different from asking "how" they can do X. That's a common problem people have when reviewing questions, because those terms are often used one in place of another, this even if they are not asking the same thing at all. Truth is, most people tell "how can I defeat X" is -often- as a wording shortcut to "What would be the most favorable favorable action/situation through which someone/something will have (the) high(est) chance of defeating X?". The original wording is certainly under-technical and over-shortened, but the meaning virtually stays the same as the long version. And none of the versions asks "what their character 'should' do" : They ask "what they 'can' do".

And really, it infuriates me to see that again and again, people think that the story drives the success of a chosen tactics, rather than tactics serving as the structure and limitation of the story, leaving it out only when it's not what matters (mainly for the [rule of cool](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BulletTime)).

To sum up, refusing tactics as story-based is telling that dices can roll on whichever number you want **absolutely every time**, because that's your story, not a [world rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability). It's telling that [society and culture questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8312)<sup>2</sup> about school uniforms are off-topic because one delinquant student may choose to wear their casual attires anyway, regardless of the established social norms and its sources (e.g. : Authoritarian, strong formalism...). It is refusing questions about [how can spies cross ravines](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8407) for being story-based, because spies and their gadget manufactor can choose to do whatever they want, regardless if the solution is effective for the purpose or not. Refusing this is telling that any and every questions that involve some statistical variance are off-topic, because individual rolls/values are random, and absurdly independent on what the world tells you should happen "on average".

And from that last point I will conclude with this : Refusing tactic questions as a general rule because they are story-based, not "[objectively true in all circumstances](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10314)" is at its core refusing every questions that involve people... Or let's go further, any question. Yes, because unless you believe that your world elements and individuals is entirely and strictly [deterministic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinism)/fatalistic, there will be variance, individual circumstances, undetailed holes in the question leading to one best answer or another.

And tactics are far, very far from being the only study domain to "suffer" from that variance.

---

<sup>1 : The greatest illustration of this is games as they're often simplification and abstraction of the real-world. When someone says you're in a bad spot in chess, they actually mean your chances to win are lower than any other situation, this regardless of your opponent's actual ELO. When in Street fighter pro-players advise you to keep away from the arena's corners it's -among other things- because you lose the ability to move away from your opponent, losing effectively a defensive option. It's not because your opponent will suddenly become sharper and/or smarter because "story!".</sup>
<sup>2 : By the way, I do have to note that strategy and tactics are fundamentally culture-based, check how romans were using more agressive tactics than others as the [society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dignitas_(Roman_concept)) promoted more glorious than cautious leaders. Another reason it is more than a "character choice".</sup>

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to disagree with JBH, partly to play Devils' Advocate, partly because I like Military tagged questions and Partly because I like to Argue (Who knew?)

First point:

Just because users misuse tags, is not - IMO, a reason in-of-itself to get rid of the Tag. Consider the Magic tag or the Hard Science tag that get abused waaaaaaaaaaay more than the Tactics Tag - whilst I hear the counterpoint that whilst they have a lot of chaff, they also have a lot more Wheat - I don't think this, on it's own, is reason enough.

Second point:

Many of the questions which could (and perhaps should) be tagged tactics... Aren't. Case in point - this question [Lever action or primitive Bolt for an Army modernizing at speed?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/253208/lever-action-or-primitive-bolt-for-an-army-modernizing-at-speed) - A large component of the reasons why you would go one or the other comes down to the Military Doctrine, AKA Tactics - I (briefly) mentioned it in my answer about massed Volley Fire being a key part of the Doctrine of most European militaries of the time. If the Doctrine was centred around a different set of Tactics, it would lead to a different outcome.

If people are not using the Tag when it is, IMO, appropriate, that also is not a reason for it not to be used.

Thirdly - and this is probably the key part when it comes to *worldbuilding* - Considering Tactics can have major implications on the authenticity of a World.

I'm going to cite my favourite Universe - Warhammer 40K - 'Why would a supersoldier in the future have a preference for Melee weapons?! It's Stupid' is a common refrain heard by people just getting into the universe.

However from a Worldbuilding perspective - when you say 'There are more enemies than a Space Marine can feasibly carry Ammo for and a Melee Weapon never runs dry, They are armored against ranged attacks and they use Teleporters/Drop pods to get directly into the Enemy in order to assault them in Melee' - the *tactics* make the world believable.

So, let's assume that Games Workshop were posting on here way back in 1987 and said:

"I am doing a futuristic world where Supersoldiers have a heavy reliance on Melee, What Tactics would make this believable?" (with additional fluff so that the question didn't fall afoul of our Brain Storming rules) - That would be a valid Tactics question.

**Counter-proposal**

a combined 'Weapons and Tactics' Tags could be a compromise here if the rest of the Meta Posters are dead-set on it's removal. As IMO Weapons and their Tactics are intrinsically intertwined.

Comment: What is issued to a unit isn’t a matter of tactics but doctrine. In general anything related to in world plans is a poor fit for a worldbuilding site, since any plan will be entirely dependent upon the specific conditions the planners are operating under.

Comment: @sphennings - I see your point - although I would counter with 'Tactics is the real-world application of Doctrine' - and that those elements *can absolutely* be a part of world building - say for example someone 'designs' a new weapon in their world and they are unsure of how such a weapon would *realistically* be employed - that could be a valid tactics question *if the answer is about a combat scenario* -

Comment: But can they be part of worldbuilding in a way that is appropriate for this site? BTW how will my character use this weapon is a context dependent scenario driven question. While how will a military incorporate this weapon into their forces is a question of doctrine. The key point is that doctrine doesn’t change with the scenario while tactics are by their nature dependent upon them. Asking how a scenario will play out is not a suitable question for this site.

Comment: A real-life application of doctrine is a question that should be closed as too story-based. Such a question could only remain open if every story-based aspect of the example scenario or circumstance was defined by the OP. That, of course, is the problem with every TSB question.

Comment: @JBH - I see your point, but I disagree - specifically on the notion of my WH40K example - that question could be asked, legitimately, without being too story based and it would be within our purview as World Building - If you were to have a weapon and it's usage in the world was incongruent with the rest of the World Building - that breaks the immersion and feel of the world.

Comment: Preference? :-) From the [help/on-topic], "If on the other hand you aren’t sure what a character (be it an individual or organization) should do, that is out of scope for the site...." No question about any kind of choice is on-topic. One can ask every question about the development of the weapon... but not the circumstances about its use. That's always been illegitimate. Technically, no question is legitimate if not asked from the perspective of receiving one best answer (c.f. the "all answers having equal value" prohibition in the [help/dont-ask]).

Comment: @TheDemonLord There's a difference between a question that if it was differently asked is appropriate for this site and a question that in its current form is appropriate for this site. Most questions if asked the right way can be asked here. However unless they're actually asked that way they should be closed until in their current form are appropriate. I can't ask who would win in a fight but I can ask if a certain armor renders an opponents weapons ineffective. I can't ask for help with my chemistry homework but asking about the same problem as it impacts the world I'm building would be ok.

Comment: As I see it, the problem with Tactics is that, ultimately, they are the choice or action of one or more characters. I would therefore argue that any question using this tag is literally asking "what should a character do" and almost screams *close me for being story based!*